# javascript replace() regexp returning syntax error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, yql

I'm trying out YQL with Jquery, and some javascript replace regexp returns a syntax error:

```
data = data.replace(/<?/body[^>]*>/g,'');
data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[Ss]*?</noscript>/g,'');
data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[Ss]*?</script>/g,'');
data = data.replace(/<script.*/>/,'');
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with the syntax and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance

Complete script: http://pastebin.com/49YUKTdV

Comment: Why have you provided it commented out?

Comment: Which line gives error? E.g. look at line 1 - you use `/` as pattern boundary and then again inside regex.

Comment: I edited your question (removed comments). Now the code colorer lets you see the exact source of the problem. Use an editor that has proper code coloring, it will be much easier to spot problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

your `/`s in your regex are breaking it, you need to escape them all:

```
/<script.*/>/
          ^----- this one needs to be escaped

/<script.*\/>/
```

Comment: escape character ! gosh why didn't I think of that.. Thanks for providing a quick and correct answer!